# Listar dados do MySql no formato de TABELAS dentro das TABs Bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql

Caros, estou criando um sistema de listagem de produtos em que os mesmos sejam apresentados de acordo com sua categoria.

O sistema funciona da seguinte forma:

Os dados são cadastrados no BD "mercado" na tabela produtos contendo 4 campos (id, produto, categoria e preço) e as categorias são cadastradas na tabela categoria contendo 2 campos (id e categoria).

Na página produtos.php deve ser apresentado da seguinte forma:

As categorias são relacionadas em TABs e os produtos em Tabela, de acordo com sua categoria, ou seja se tenho a categoria "Bebidas" deve ser apresentado todas as Bebidas desta categoria na TAB Bebidas e assim por diante.

Porém não estou conseguindo fazer isso, só está sendo apresentado os produtos da primeira categoria e repetindo nas demais.

Segue o código que estou usando para construção:

Página Produtos.php

```html
<div class="container">
   <h2>Lista de Produtos por Categoria</h2>
   <br><br>
   <?php include_once 'select_produtos.php'; ?>
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-pills nav-justified">
    <?php echo $categorias_menu; ?>
   </ul>
   <div class="tab-content">
    <table class="table table-hover">
     <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Código</th>
        <th scope="col">Produto</th>
        <th class=" text-center" scope="col">Valor</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <?php
      echo $lista_produtos;
      ?>
      </tr> 
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Página Select_produtos.php

```html
<?php

if ( !isset( $seguranca ) ) {
 exit;
}
include_once 'conexao.php';

$categorias_sql = "SELECT * FROM categorias ORDER BY id ASC";
$categorias_result = mysqli_query( $connect, $categorias_sql );
$categorias_menu = '';

$produtos_query = "SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY produto ASC";
$produtos_result = mysqli_query( $connect, $produtos_query ) or die ("database error:". mysqli_error($connect));
$lista_produtos = '';
$i = 0;

//EXIBIR O MENU - ABAS - DE CADA CATEGORIA 
while ( $categorias = mysqli_fetch_array( $categorias_result ) ) {
 if ( $i == 0 ) {
  $categorias_menu .= '
  <li class="active">
   <a href="#' . $categorias[ "id" ] . '" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">' . $categorias[ "categoria" ] . '</a>
  </li>
  ';
  $lista_produtos .= '
  <div id="' . $categorias[ "id" ] . '" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  ';
 } else {
  $categorias_menu .= '
  <li>
   <a href="#' . $categorias[ "id" ] . '" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">' . $categorias[ "categoria" ] . '</a>
  </li>
  ';
  $lista_produtos .= '
  <div id="' . $categorias[ "id" ] . '" class="tab-pane fade">
  ';
 }
 $i++; 
 //Verfica se existem produtos na tabela
 if(!mysqli_num_rows($produtos_result)) {
  $lista_produtos .= '<br>Produto não encontrado!';
 }else{
  //LISTANDO PRODUTOS NO FORMATO DE TABELA
  while ( $sub_row = mysqli_fetch_array( $produtos_result ) ) {
   if($sub_row['categoria_id'] == $categorias['id']){
    $lista_produtos .= '<tr>';
    $lista_produtos .= '<td class="text-uppercase">' . utf8_encode($sub_row[ "id" ]) . '</td>';
    $lista_produtos .= '<td class="text-uppercase">' . utf8_encode($sub_row[ "produto" ]) . '</td>';
    $lista_produtos .= '<td class="text-uppercase text-center">R$ ' . $sub_row[ "preco" ] . '</td>';
   }
  }
 }
}
$lista_produtos .= '<div style="clear:both">';
?>
```

Onde está meu erro ou o que estou deixando de fazer aqui?

Segue imagem da tela como quero que fique.

[image: Exemplo da tabela dentro das TABs] 
Mas ao clicar na próxima ABA os dados apresentados são os mesmos da anterior "Laticínios", mesmo tendo registros relacionados às próximas categorias.

Obrigado.

Comment: Olá, tente colocar uma variável de para contar os produtos e ir somando dentro do WHILE.

Answer (score 0):

Seu select não tem where?

Por mais que esteja exibindo apenas os laticínios, o seu select retornou todos os campos da tabela. Enquanto tiver poucos registros ok, mas quando essa tabela crescer o sistema vai ter um sério problema de performance.

Passa via get o id das categorias e verifica se ele está setado, se não estiver, defina uma categoria default e retorna ou coloca a lista de categorias para o usuário escolher.

```
if(isset($_GET['categoria']))
{
    $categoriaId = $_GET['categoria'];
}
else
{
    $categoriaId = 1;
}

$produtos_query = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE categoria_id = {$categoriaId} ORDER BY produto ASC";
```

Lá em baixo, onde você atribui o link das categorias, passa essa URL:

```
<li>
    <a href="Pagina_Produtos.php?categoria=' . $categorias[ "id" ] . '" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">' . $categorias[ "categoria" ] . '</a>
</li>
```

Ai como você vai deixar ativo o menu certo é outra questão. Eu utilizo javascript.